# In Grails, how do I return to the calling current view from a controller?

Tags: grails, view, controller

Below is a very simple controller with a "search" action that is fired from g:submitButton in a gsp file. My question is, instead of redirecting to the "index" action and view, how do I return to the view that contained the submit button that called this controller's search action?

```
class DefaultSearchController {
    def searchableService

    def index = {
    }

    def search = {
        def query = params.query
        if(!query){
            redirect(action:"index", params:params)
        }

        try{
            def searchResults =  searchableService.searchEvery( query )
            redirect(action:"index", searchResults)
        }
        catch( e ){
            params.errors = "${e.toString()}"
            redirect(action: "index", params:params)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search action is going to be called from various places, I would pass in a parameter to it telling search controller where to redirect to or which view to render the search results with.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the most difficult answer is the one staring you in the face.